# Where is the build.gradle file located for my Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-studio

Where is the `build.gradle` file located for my Android project?

I'm trying to follow along with [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library), but I can't make necessary changes to my `build.gradle` file to use the support library.

Comment: Are you using android studio?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It will be located in the project root unless you have set a custom location. To generate a `build.gradle` file, use [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) and export the project as `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 1):

The location of **build.gradle (Project)** is in the root project

and the         **build.gradle (app)** is in the /app/build.gradle of the projet

Answer (score 0):

The app level build.gradle file is located inside your project folder under app/build.gradle. for eg: if your project name is MyApplication
MyApplication/app/build.gradle.
At this location, you will be adding dependencies for your project.
There will be one more build.gradle file under your project folder immediately in new versions( As of April 2017). But to my opinion you never play with this file.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Clicker here to see]

The folder is present on the left hand side below.